# Cygwin - ypcat command equivalent

Tags: cygwin, command

I've been trying to find the equivalent command for the UNIX ypcat utility for Cygwin, but there is almost no documentation for it i regards to its presence (if any) for Cygwin.  Can anybody help me find or teach me its equivalent, and if they can a brief explanation on how to use it if it differs from ypcat (it happened to me that Cygwin uses aspell for spell checking, replacing ispell or spell, and does not use the same entry format).  TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone made a port, but the files are no longer available at the specified domain, it seems.

http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2003-09/msg00144.html

You may have to contact the owner by e-mail to get a copy.